# Rest Sharp Execute<Int> fails due to cast exception

Tags: restsharp

I have this:

```
public Int32 NumberOfLocationsForCompany(int companyId)
{
        var response = _curl.ResetRequest()
            .WithPath(LOCATION_URL)
            .AddParam("companyId", companyId.ToString())
            .RequestAsGet()
            .ProcessRequest<Int32>();

        return response;
}
```

that calls this at the end.

```
    public T ProcessRequest<T>() where T : new()
    {
        var response = _client.Execute<T>(_request);

        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            throw response.ErrorException;
        }
        return response.Data;
    }
```

but I get this error. I don't get why it's trying to map an int to a collection or why it's Int64 vs the 32 I specified.: **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.**

When I hit the api directly this is what I get back

```
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">17</int>
```

I feel it's something I'm not understanding about Rest Sharp. I tell the execute method to expect an Int, it receives and int, but is trying to map it to a collection. Why and where does the collection come from?

I have noticed that when I look into the base response object's Content the appropriate result "17" is present, why can't Rest Sharp find it? and still where is it finding the Collection?

Comment: FIXED. I just created another method that returns the content. I'll use it when I'm not expecting Objects. Hopefully that's the appropriate way to handle this.

Comment: You may answer yourself if you've fixed it yourself, so that others can see how you did it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the response object I found the return value was in Content vs in Data. I found this to be true whenever I was not returning an object or list of objects.

So now when I'm expecting an int, string, bool, etc I use the following and cast the type of the return value:

```
    public string ProcessRequestWithValue()
    {
        var response = _client.Execute(_request);

        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            throw response.ErrorException;
        }

        return response.Content;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the actual problem. This is more of a (painful) workaround. When an API is shared by other clients (whose post is expecting a `int` return, not an object, it becomes a hassle definition different controllers/actions.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot be of help here, I no longer have access to this code and have not used Rest Sharp since. I've been using NodeJS for all APIs. @SergeP