# RestSharp unable to cast object when awaiting for response

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

Using RestSharp I'm building an API to perform CRUD operations given a datatype/object.

My **`CrudAbstract`** class is generic and has the following:

```
public virtual async Task<keyType> Post(dto item)
{
    try
    {
        var request = await _client.GetRequestAsync(_path);
        request.Method = RestSharp.Method.POST;
        request.AddJsonBody(item);
        var result = await _client.ExecuteRequestAsync<keyType>(request);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    throw new Exception("Was not able to process crud post operation.");
}
```

My **`WebClient`** class has the following:

```
Entities = new CrudAbstract<DtoEntity, int>("/entities", this); // in constructor
// So the keyType from definition above is int (Int32)
```

The post method in this class is

```
public async Task<T> ExecuteRequestAsync<T>(IRestRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await GetClient().ExecuteTaskAsync<T>(request);

        // Exception occurs here. The above statement is unable to finish.

        var data = response.Data;
        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log exception
    }
    throw new Exception("Was not able to process restclient execute async method.");
}
```

My Api **`EntitiesController`** has the following:

```
    public int Post(DtoEntity value)
    {
        using (var db = // some database...)
        {
            try
            {
                // Upsert object into database here
                //... value.Id no longer null at this point

                /*
                   The problem occurs here. I only want to return the ID of the object 
                   (value.Id). I do not want to return the whole object (value)
                */
                return value.Id;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Log exception
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Was not able to process entities post method.");
    }
```

The exception I get is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

This is basically saying it is unable to cast the object `int` (which I have returned in the post with `value.Id`) to a `DtoEntity` object (which is the actual object on which CRUD operations were performed).

What am I doing wrong?

I have placed `typeof` and `.getType()` onto each `keyType`, `T`, and `value.Id`, and all of them are `Int32`. Is it in the RestSharp library that the problem occurs? At what stage is there a casting of `int` to a `DtoEntity` in the line:

```
var response = await GetClient().ExecuteTaskAsync<T>(request);
```

**Note:** when I change the return type of the post method in my controller to `DtoEntity` and change the `value.Id` to just `value` it works. The `response` is received, and the `response.Data` is the `DtoEntity` object.

I've seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678834/rest-sharp-executeint-fails-due-to-cast-exception) but not found a solution yet.

Comment: Any luck? Could you post a full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: A (temporary) solution that worked for me was to use the `Execute` (instead of `ExecuteTaskAsync`) in an `await Task.Run` then `JsonConvert.Deserialise` the result into type `T`. Also actually the exception wasn't even trying to convert the response data into my type `DtoEntity` but some other RestSharp defined `IDictionary` object.

Comment: Why are you doing await Task.Run?

Comment: The method I am implementing `ExecuteRequestAsync` is an `async Task`. I need some sort of `await` statement inside it otherwise it will complain. Initially I was using RestSharp's `ExecuteTaskAsync` which is a task I can `await` - this however produced exceptions. RestSharp's `Execute` is not async, so I have to wrap it in some kind of `Task` I can `await`. `await Task.Run` is the one to do it.

Comment: Scheduling  a synchronous method to the threadpool does not make it async. (See [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html).) If you're going with `Execute`, it's much more correct to change your method signature to stop pretending it's async, which it isn't. If you absolutely must keep that method signature for whatever reason, go with `Task.FromResult` instead. I still think I can help you get the async version working (far preferable) if you post your stack trace.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try my [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl) library and see if you have better luck. Similar to RestSharp except it's async only and uses HttpClient and Json.NET under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for that link on Task.Run (I wasn't too sure if I was on the right track). Also [here's](http://pastebin.com/5P0UHxxB) the stack trace of the exception. Flurl looks interesting.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you've spotted a bug in RestSharp. RestSharp internally uses a JSON parser called SimpleJson (borrowed from the [Facebook .NET SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json)). It appears that this parser is correctly deserializing the response body to a number (since JSON is untyped it uses Int64 to be safe), but the RestSharp's [JsonDeserializer class](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Deserializers/JsonDeserializer.cs) attempts to cast this result to an `IDictionary` in the first line of this method:

```
    private object FindRoot(string content)
    {
        var data = (IDictionary<string, object>)SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(content);

        if (RootElement.HasValue() && data.ContainsKey(RootElement))
        {
            return data[RootElement];
        }

        return data;
    }
```

I think your options are:

- File an issue with the RestSharp team.
- Get the raw string body and cast it to an int yourself (may be the path of least resistance).
- Try a different library.